# Clearing Calendar.HOUR adds hundreds of days

Tags: java, android, calendar, gregorian-calendar

I'm using the lines of code:

```
1  GregorianCalendar cal = (GregorianCalendar) date.clone();
2  cal.clear(Calendar.HOUR);
```

When using this code in a unit test - it runs just fine. However when running it on my Android device, it seems to break. Here is what my debugger says:

After line 1: 
`cal.getTimeInMillis() = 1426022494179`
After line 2: `cal.getTimeInMillis() = 1450905694179`

I've also tried `cal.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0)` and it does the same thing.

**EDIT:** After some testing, it appears that setting or clearing anything on the cal object immediately puts me to December 24 of the year you are currently in. However, once the initial switch to Dec 24 happens, the Calendar then acts normally.

Comment: Any chance the reason you insist on using `clone()` is that you're actually using a (custom) subclass of `GregorianCalendar`? `Calendar` objects store fields separately from the actual date object, and not every operation keeps them in sync, all the time, especially not, if you're created your own subclass that does who-knows-what.

Comment: No - I am using the GregorianCalendar from Android SDK 21.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue. It appears Android SDK 21 has a bug - when using getActualMaximum(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR) on the GregorianCalendar, it puts the object into a state such that if you use a set() call before a get() call, it will put your date to December 31 or 23 (depending on the year).

Comment: I almost didn't believe you. Tested it, reproduced it, checked the code. I believe you now. Beware of `Calendar`...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
      Calendar cal4 = Calendar.getInstance();
      cal4.setTime((Date)d.clone());    // <-- Update 
      Log.d(TAG,"cal4 time: " + cal4.getTime().toString());

      cal4.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);

      Log.d(TAG,"cal4 time: " + cal4.getTime().toString());
```

Output:

```
cal4 time: Fri Mar 27 19:02:55 EDT 2015
cal4 time: Fri Mar 27 00:02:55 EDT 2015
```

Comment: The times I get: Tue Mar 17 04:29:16 GMT+13:00 2015
Thu Dec 24 00:29:16 GMT +13:00 2015

Comment: Try running my exact code, the date in your response does not reflect that you have tried it.

Comment: Your code works. I get the correct day. (However - I still need it to work with a clone. I cannot get an instance of the Calendar - this function must work with any generic given date)

Comment: Call `setTime()` on the Calendar instance created.  See updated code.